# How to display images from ObservableCollection in mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, bitmap

I'm still tyring to get my head around MVVM.
I got stuck on displaying my images which paths are stored in an observableCollection. In the past I could make it would with code behind in the view but now when I'm trying to implement MVVM on my project and it doesn't show any images anymore.

This is the code I have in the viewmodel

```
private ObservableCollection<Image> _selectedImageList = new ObservableCollection<Image>();
public ObservableCollection<Image> SelectedImageList
{
        get { return _findImageList; }
        set { _findImageList = value; }
}

public ImageLibraryViewModel()
{
        string dbConnectionString = @"Data Source =movieprepper.sqlite;";
        SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnectionString);
        cnn.Open();
        string Query = "Select* from images";
        SQLiteDataAdapter sda = new SQLiteDataAdapter(Query, cnn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        cnn.Close();

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.Substring(0, (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.Length - 10));
            string name = row["path"].ToString();
            Uri uri = new Uri(path + name);

            Image I = new Image(uri.ToString(), row["path"].ToString(), row["title"].ToString());

            SelectedImageList.Add(I);
        }
}
```

And this is what I have in the XAML

```
 <ListBox  ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedImageList}" dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Thumbnail}" Width="200"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Thumbnail}"></TextBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

In the text that's binded to the thumbnail I can clearly read the path to which the image points at, but the image doesn't display in the list. In the past without the MVVM, the Image Source converted the filepath automatically into an image.  Does Anybody know where I went wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: It might help if you share how the Thumbnail property is defined on your Image class. What type is it? Also, what value is it returning from its getter in your problem case? I don't see anything in the code provided that would itself cause the issue you are describing.

Comment: Is `BaseDirectory.Substring(0, (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.Length - 10))` meant to cut off the "bin\Debug\" part of the current directory? You should not do that. What about the release version, where it is "bin\Release\", or when the application is installed with a completely different path? The root folder of the images might instead be a configuration setting of your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ImageSource` does not actually convert from a string at runtime all that well. In fact, you likely have a couple `System.Data` exceptions indicating that the conversion is failing.

What you will usually do here is use an `IValueConverter` to take your path and make a `BitmapImage` out of it.

Your XAML becomes:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ThumbnailPath, Converter={StaticResource PathToImageConverter}"/>
```

The `Convert` method in the converter would be something like:

```
public object Convert(...)
{
     return new BitmapImage(new Uri((string)value));
}
```

Comment: The important thing is that you bind to either an absolute URI or a string representation of an absolute URI. Problems usually arise when you try to use relative paths. I have never needed a custom converter when using absolute paths, but there may be cases I simply have not run into.

Comment: @Xavier Maybe I've just never used absolute paths :) but I've always used the converter.

Comment: Besides what Xavier has said, you could simplify your Convert method by using the BitmapImage constructor that takes an Uri parameter. You would thus save the BeginInit and EndInit calls, and just `return new BitmapImage(new Uri((string)value));`